# Create a delegate which returns enum's underlying int, without knowing the enum type at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, system.reflection

I am writing a settings system which relies on adding attributes to properties, and then using reflection.

For example, I create sliders by adding a SliderAttribute to float properties, then finding all those attributes and creating delegates to modify the associated property like so:

```
Func<float> getterDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<float>), arg, property.GetGetMethod()) as Func<float>;
Action<float> setterDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<float>), arg, property.GetSetMethod()) as Action<float>;

settingObj = new Slider(sliderAttribute, getterDelegate, setterDelegate);
```

Now, I'd like to create multiple choice objects by applying the same logic to enum values. That is I want to generate getter/setter delegates which modify the enum property via the underlying type (which we can assume is always int.)

The ideal would be the following, which returns the error `ArgumentException: method return type is incompatible`. Same result if I use the 'Enum' type.

```
Func<int> getterDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), arg, property.GetGetMethod()) as Func<int>;
Action<int> setterDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), arg, property.GetSetMethod()) as Action<int>;

settingObj = new MultipleChoice(multipleChoiceAttribute, getterDelegate, setterDelegate, property.PropertyType);
```

Comment: Do you have to give the constructor of `MultipleChoice` a `Action<int>` and `Func<int>`? Or any does `Action<TheActualEnumType>` and `Func<TheActualEnumType>` work too?

Comment: @Sweeper the issue is I don't know the enum type at the stage where I'm creating the delegates.

Comment: My point is, that you _do_ know the enum type. It's just `property.PropertyType`. And you _can_ create an instance of `Action<TheActualEnumType>`. It will only have a compile time type of `Delegate`, of course. My question is, what parameters does the `MultipleChoice` constructor take? Does it take a `Delegate` as parameter? If not, then there is no point in creating `Action<TheActualEnumType>` in the first place, and I won't post that as an answer.

Comment: MultipleChoice takes the parameters: (MultipleChoiceInfoAttribute info, Func<int> getter, Action<int> setter, Type enumType)

I can access the enum type in property.PropertyType, but I can hardly use that as the type parameter in the "CreateDelegate" function?

Comment: You _can_ use that in the first parameter of `CreateDelegate`, but since `MultipleChoice` only wants a `Action<int>`, you can't pass it directly to the constructor. Let me see if I can come up with something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create delegates that return and take the actual enum type, like this:

```
Delegate getterEnumDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType), arg, property.GetGetMethod()
);
Delegate setterEnumDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType), arg, property.GetSetMethod()
);
```

To convert these into `Action<int>` and `Func<int>`, you just need to do:

```
Func<int> getterDelegate = () => (int)getterEnumDelegate.DynamicInvoke();
Action<int> setterDelegate = x => setterEnumDelegate.DynamicInvoke(x);
```